# Boostrap showing weird behavior

Tags: html, css, margin

I don't know why Bootstrap is doing this. I want the whole background of the website to be black and for that I'm doing this inside HTML file

```
<body>
    <div id="fullWrapper">
        <section id="welcomeSection">
            <div class="container">
                <p style="margin-top:30px;">Welcome to the website. This website was made to test the light and dark modes with bootstrap</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

and inside css file.

```
#fullWrapper {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    height: 1000px;
}
```

but the output is leaving a white space of 30px from the top. See this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ne1r6.png)

Comment: Why not just add the background color to body? `body { background-color: black; }`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton its not working. the background stays white if i do it to body {}

Comment: @Jer How does it not solve the problem? If OP wants the whole page to be black, the whole body can be colored black lol

Comment: It's an overflow issue in the parent DIV and has nothing to do with Bootstrap.

Comment: True . You just self putted <p> with margin-top : 30 it's not bootstrap fault.Remove margin-top just.

Answer (score -1):

That space is from the paragraph `margin-top: 30px;` which is caused from margin collapsing. If there is no border, padding, etc. on the parent element to separate `margin-top` on the first child block, then those margins collapse.

Here is further explanation about margin collapsing on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

There are multiple ways to get rid of that white space. Remove the margin from the paragraph and replace it with `padding-top: 30px;` or add at least `padding-top: 1px;` to either the `.container` or `#welcomeSection` divs.

Comment: this is not enough as an explanation. Margin is meant to add space oustide the element and inside it's parent container, so you need to say that we have margin-collpasing issue which make this margin go outside and thus creating this issue

Comment: Ok I'll update my answer. Thank you for the suggestion.